# Spring batch - define split based on the some of flows of previous split completion status

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have the spring batch defined as below.

1) Step1 ,Step2,Step3 and Step4 are running parallel using split.
2) Wanted to trigger another split based on below conditions.

step5 - once step1 ,step2 and step3 are completed. 
step6 - once step1,step2 and step4 are completed

```html
<job id="job1">
    <split id="splitForSet_A" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="splitForSet_B">
        <flow><step id="step1" parent="s1"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step2" parent="s2"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step3" parent="s3"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step4” parent="s4”/></flow>
    </split>

 <another split>
<flow><step id="step5” /></flow>  — This is should start once step1 ,step2 and step3 are completed.
<flow><step id="step6” /></flow>  —   This should start once the step1,step2 and step4 are completed.
</another split>
```

Comment: I don't see how you would do that but you can try to have a subflow for (step1, step2, step3) + a decider on this subflow status to trigger step5. And do the same for step1, step2, step4 + decider for step 6.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine , if I use the sub flow , i will be running step1 ,step2 and step3 in sequential , I don't see a way to run them in parallel.

Comment: No, a parallel flow can have parallel subflows. Nothing prevents you from having a subflow running in parallel with another subflow under the same parent flow.